# how can i run a spock groovy test in java method

Tags: groovy, spock

i load a [DatabaseDrivenSpec.groovy](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/DataDrivenSpec.groovy) in a spring controller method.but i don't know how to invokeMethod the method in the groovy script. anybody can give me a advice?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spock")
public class PmsTreeConfluentService {
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PmsTreeConfluentService.class);        

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/spock", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ColumnResponseBody
    List runTestMock() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, CompilationFailedException, IOException {             
        GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());  
        File sourceFile = new File("test/groovy/DatabaseDrivenSpec.groovy");  
        Class testGroovyClass = classLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(sourceFile));  
        GroovyObject instance = (GroovyObject)testGroovyClass.newInstance();//proxy         
//      instance.invokeMethod(arg0, arg1)

        instance = null;  
        testGroovyClass = null;  
        return null;
    }               
}
```

with the guide http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html

```
def binding = new Binding()
def engine = new GroovyScriptEngine([tmpDir.toURI().toURL()] as URL[])          

while (true) {
    def greeter = engine.run('ReloadingTest.groovy', binding)                   
    println greeter.sayHello()                                                  
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

i just want to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/spock/test/spock then run the DatabaseDrivenSpec.groovy test case.

Comment: Your PmsTreeConfluentService looks like production code which normally would not depend (aka import) on test code. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry it is.a java method.i just paste it in this format it can't.when i define the above code.

i just want to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/spock/test/spock then run the DatabaseDrivenSpec.groovy test case

Comment: Might I ask why? Also do you need to load the test from the file system instead of the jar?

Comment: yes we do need load test script from file or a database. not jar. the groovy script can hot deploy. we want a online test,not only auto developmet test.and test on a web console.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run spock specifications programmatically, you can try something like this:

```
import spock.util.EmbeddedSpecRunner

EmbeddedSpecRunner runner = new EmbeddedSpecRunner()
// There is a lot of runXXX methods, use the apropriate one
runner.runXXXX(<Class of test: testGroovyClass> or <String of test code>)
```

Spock is based on Junit Runners, see about it [here](http://www.mscharhag.com/java/understanding-junits-runner-architecture) and some example code [here](https://gist.github.com/boggebe/fdef8478fded92612fdc)

And, I don't know the problem you're trying to solve, but I strongly recommend running your test using tools already available for this purpose. Like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) for example.